# Howto activate named time zones

Tags: mysql, azure, timezone, azure-cli

I want to automate the installation and configuration of a mysql server using azure cli.

The installation works well using `azure mysql server create`, however the configuration using `azure mysql server configuration set -n time_zone --value Europe/Paris` fails due to the following error:


`Deployment failed. Correlation ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. The value 'Europe/Paris' for configuration 'time_zone' is not valid. The allowed values are '[+|-][0]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]|[+|-][1][0-2]:[0-5][0-9]|SYSTEM'.`

As I read in the [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-g11n-excerpt/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html) I could enable named time zones executing the following sql `SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;`, but unfortunately my user would need super privilege for this to succeed and this is [impossible in azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-limits). 
The other approach would be to run `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` but this is not available using azure cli.

Is there any other way to activate named time zones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Azure DB for MySQL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-server-parameters-using-cli#working-with-the-time-zone-parameter):

> **Populating the time zone tables**
> The time zone tables on your server can be populated by calling the `mysql.az_load_timezone` stored procedure from a tool like the MySQL command line or MySQL Workbench.
>
> ```sql
> CALL mysql.az_load_timezone();
> ```

Also, in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-limits) (you linked to in your question):

> Upon initial deployment, an Azure for MySQL server includes systems tables for time zone information, but these tables are not populated. The time zone tables can be populated by calling the `mysql.az_load_timezone` stored procedure from a tool like the MySQL command line or MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

According to Error message the format should be one of these three:

> [+|-][0]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]

eg. -04:30

or

> [+|-][1][0-2]:[0-5][0-9]

e.g -12:00

or

> SYSTEM

So have you tried doing it with quotes?

> azure mysql server configuration set -n time_zone --value
> "Europe/Paris"

Comment: But I want to use Europe/Paris or other named aquivalents.

Comment: @UNeverNo what you want and what the command accepts is two different things.

Comment: If you read the linked docs, you'll find out that named time zones are possible. My question is - howto achieve this in the azure environment.

Comment: @UNeverNo you are running an azure command not a MySQL command. You need to look at the correct documentation

Comment: @UNeverNo updated my answer with a suggestion of adding quotes around the timezone name.

Answer (score 0):

```
CALL mysql.az_load_timezone();
```

Call this stored procedure from your session on the server,
If you are running the `mysql.az_load_timezone` command from MySQL Workbench, you may need to turn off safe update mode first using `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0` or in Preferences->SQL Editor->Safe Updates(), and back to connect to your mysql server.